# How to send React Component as props

Tags: reactjs

Hello I'm tryed thinking in React using ES6 and I have one problem. Look this example code es5:

```js
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
    <div>
     <H1 content=<P/>></H1>
    </div>
    );
  }
});

var H1 = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
    <div>
     <h1>hello from parent </h1>
      {this.props.content}
    </div>
    );
  }
});

var P = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <p>hello from children</p>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

How do this the same using ES6 classes? I have tryed something like this: But it doesn't work coretly. Is it possible using ES6 React Components?

Comment: You have forgotten to add what you tried. There is nothing here that would changing to classes make any more difficult. Simply follow the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes . FWIW, your code should be `content={<P/>}`, be it ES5 or ES6.

Comment: For ES5 it's working good, but ES6 doesn't read it. Thanks much. But is it compatible with React? I always thought that props should return stricte data.

Comment: *"For ES5 it's working good, but ES6 doesn't read it."* JSX is completely independent from the language you are using. *"But is it compatible with React?"* Not sure what exactly you mean here. *"I always thought that props should return stricte data"* What do you mean with "strict data"?

Comment: I have to correct myself, `content=<P/>` is valid JSX. https://facebook.github.io/jsx/

Comment: Most likely you did something wrong when converting to classes. But without seeing your code we don't know what it is. Again, I suggest to follow the documentation. Put differently: How to pass a component as prop is exactly the same in ES6 and ES5.

Comment: Thanks, I have to read docs more. I did it on purpose. I have popup bootstrap with {props.content} which return that popup content what I will pass in props. I was wondering about props.children but I decided to experiment with React

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Hello extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <H1>
          <P/>
        </H1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class H1 extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
       <h1>hello from parent </h1>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class P extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <p>hello from children</p>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

But you'll need to compile it first, you can use [Babel.js](https://babeljs.io/) and some other packages to make it works, like Gulp, Webpack or Grunt;

Comment: Hey, yes, I thought about props children but i wanted send my component as props. But thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between passing a component as prop in ES6 and ES5:

```
content=<P/>
```

While JSX is an extension of JavaScript (ECMAScript), it is incompletely independent of the version you are using.

If you encounter an issue then likely because something else in your conversion is wrong.